# Does the money supply increase when more types of money are added to the economy?

Tags: macroeconomics, money-supply

In some country, the currency is called "dollars". There are 100 trillion (100T) total dollars in existence. People trade these dollars for goods and services.

A new fintech startup comes along and prints a bunch of paper notes saying "rallods." There are 100T total rallods in existence. The founder somehow generates a lot of hype and people start trading rallods for goods and services, at a rate of 2 rallods = 1 dollar. This rate never changes, as the trade between rallods and dollars is exactly balanced.

What is now the money supply in this country? Is it still 100T dollars, or is it 150T dollars = 300T rallods?

I expect that the economy will set prices similar to the scenario where there are 150T dollars and no rallods, or 300T rallods and no dollars. If not, please explain why.